# Accessing element of map of vector of maps (c++)

Tags: c++, stdvector

I've been working on a simple database system managment and I've come up with:

```
std::map< std::string, std::vector < std::map < std::string,
          boost::variant <std::string, size_t, double bool> > > tables;
```

I have a map (tables) of vectors (table) of maps (records) and I've allready wrote a function to read a file to it but I'm not really sure how to access the single attributes.

I can print the whole thing with:

```
for(auto table: tables)
    for(auto record : table.second)
        for(auto attribute : record) {
            std::cout << j.second;
```

I tried doing something like:

```
std::cout << tables["credentials"][2]["username"];
```

This however does not work; it only prints a blank line.

Comment: So when you print the whole thing, `tables["credentials"][2]["username"]` record is printed as not blank?

Comment: If I run the 3 for loops then the entire database gets printed but I want to access single elements. I tried with ```std::cout << tables["credentials"][2]["username"]``` and it doesn't give me any compile error but when I run it instead of printing an element of the database it just prints a blank line.

Comment: Well, managed to find the problem. For some reason the first few maps we're empty.  The problem must have been somewhere in the function that reads from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely that you are using wrong keys of the maps to access the database.

Update your code to print the contents of your database so you can see the keys also in the maps.

```
for(auto table: tables)
{
   std::cout << "Key: " << table.first << std::endl;
   for(auto record : table.second)
   {
      for(auto attribute : record)
      {
         std::cout << "Key: " << attribute.first
                   << ", Value: " << attribute.second << std::endl;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: My problem is accessing single elements. I'm not really sure how to. I tried `std::cout << tables["credentials"][2]["username"]` but this doesn't work. I checked multiple times and the keys are correct. I might be missing some `.second` and I'm not really sure where.